# Three.js - какой максимальный объем 3D модели можно загрузить с помощью ObjectLoader

Tags: json, 3d, three.js

С помощью плагина для Revit я экспортирую модель в формат three.js.
Модели до 150МБ открывались, а вот модель на 700 МБ выдала ошибку, при попытке открыть в редакторах кода, большая часть умирает от объёма, в Visual Studio вроде получилось открыть, ничем кроме количества созданных координат элементов она не отличается и собственно объёмом.
Может кто сталкивался. Ругается на неправильный парсинг:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
```

Код:

```
 // ... код для загрузки модели и ее обработки
            loadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'file';

                input.onchange = function(event) {
                    var file = event.target.files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                        var contents = event.target.result;

                        oLoad = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                        oLoad.parse(JSON.parse(contents), function(object) {
                            scene = object;
                            scene.children.forEach(function(obj3d) {
                                if (obj3d instanceof THREE.Object3D) {
                                    obj3d.children.forEach(function(mesh) {
                                        if (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                                            if (mesh.name.indexOf('TopographySurface') != -1) {
                                                console.log('got a topo');
                                                var finalGeo = mesh.geometry;
                                                finalGeo.mergeVertices();
                                                var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(subdivs);
                                                modifier.modify(finalGeo);

                                                const geometry = mesh.geometry;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                };
                            });

                            /* CREATE SKYBOX */
    ....добавление неба, света и т.д. ...
```

Файлики другие открывает на ура, а большие не хочет.
Вот и вопрос, какой-то лимит на объём или лимит на длину js?